# Flutter: Draw Shadow Underneath Custom Painted Arc

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following custom painter that draws an arc:

```dart
class ArcPainter extends CustomPainter {

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double radius = Math.min(size.width / 2, size.height);
    final center = Offset(size.width / 2.0, size.height / 2.0);

    final rect = Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius);
    final Path shadowPath = Path()
      ..arcTo(rect, Math.pi, Math.pi, true);

    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = const Color(0xFFC4C4C4)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 12;

    canvas.drawArc(rect, Math.pi, Math.pi, false, paint);
    canvas.drawShadow(shadowPath, const Color(0xff000000), 10, true);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(ProgressSemiCirclePainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: Arc picture]

How can I fix the shadow to be more convincing? Specifically:

- I don't want the whole semi-circle to be filled, I would only like a small shadow directly underneath the arc.
- I'd like to eliminate the white gap between the bottom of arc and the top of the shadow
- I'd like the shadow to extend to the end of the stroke caps on either side of the arc.